# D3 change elements based on two different datasets?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am new to d3 and no javascript expert.  I've found similar questions, but none that are quite what I'm looking for. 
I have two csv files, one with school data that looks like this
*id, name, longitude, latitude*

The other csv has network data

*id*, *netId* (this is other school ids that are connected), *hits* (this is basically how many connections are between the two schools)

I have the school data bound to circles on a map. What I'm trying to do is on a click, find each of the connected schools and transition their circles on the map based on how many connections they have.

I'm assuming this is going to need to be a series of for loops, but I'm not sure of the best way to do it. 
Currently, skipping past all the map creation stuff, I have this:

```
    var currData = [];

 d3.csv("network.csv", function(networkData){
    d3.csv("schoolData.csv", function(data) {

             //create the circles

             var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
     //bind the data
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                    .append("circle")
                    .attr("cx", function(d) {
                        return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0];
                    })
                    .attr("cy", function(d) {
                        return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1];
                    })

                //initial style of circles (will move this into a class eventually)
                    .attr("r", 5)
                    .style("fill", "orange")
                    .style("opacity", 0.75)



            //on click 
                    .on("click", function (d) {


            for (i = 0; i<= networkData.length; i++) {
                    if(d.id == networkData[i].id) {  
                    currData.push({"netId": networkData[i].netId,
                                    "hits": networkData[i].hits}
                        )}
                    };
```

This is returning the netId and hits if I log it to the console within the for loop, but I can't seem to access currData outside of the for loop. I'm not sure why. 
I am also not sure of the best way to take each of the subsequent netIds and link them back to the school data bound to the circle elements. Am I making this more complicated than necessary? Does D3 have an easy way of doing this?

When a circle is clicked on the map, I need to find the id of schools in the network for the selected school and then make a change to their circles on the map based on the number of hits.  Very much like [this](http://trends.truliablog.com/vis/metro-movers/).

The data looks like this:

```
School Data: 

id,school,lon,lat
1,UC Berkeley,-122.250502,37.872855
2,UC Los Angeles,-118.445227,34.06886
3,Cal State Los Angeles,-118.168266,34.068232
4,University of Southern California,-118.2866414,34.021801

Network Data:

id,netId,hits
193,220,1
193,229,5
193,226,1
193,49,1
124,226,11
124,201,1
278,175,7
341,227,1
341,310,2
341,135,1
101,201,1
```

Comment: Define "on a click, find each of the connected schools and transition their circles on the map based on how many connections they have." and give an example of both data sets for context.

Comment: It would also help if you could prepare a jsfiddle or something like that.

Comment: I've edited to add examples of the data and hopefully clarify. Let me know if it needs more.  I'll see if I can get a fiddle set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to select an element based on its data attribute, the easiest way to do that is to give the element a class name based on that data.  For example, all your school elements could have a class based on their id in the data, "s-1", "s-203", etc.

Then, when you find that id referenced in a row from your network data table, it is easy to select the corresponding element and change it however you want.

Here's an example.  I'm using `Array.forEach()` instead of a for loop, but it is a similar idea to what you had.  I'm not quite sure how you were using your filtered data array and why it wasn't working for you, but hopefully this will get you started:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/V5DCx/

However, instead of scanning through the net data on every click, it might be worth manipulating the data up front and including it in the school's data objects.  You can use [d3.nest](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_nest) to group the network data into sub-arrays based on the id, and then sort through the school array once, attaching the correct network sub-array to the school data before attaching the school data to your d3 graphics.  Then it will be right there waiting in your `function(d)` event handler.

Comment: You suggested using d3.nest to have the data included in the objects.  I think this will be useful for labels, appending and exiting, but I can't figure out how to use .nest to group the data. Do you have suggestions for that .nest code? Should I be using the map function to group the networks data based on id?

Comment: You use a `d3.nest()` function by first setting its key accessor functions then calling its `entries` method.  [Specs here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_nest)  [Tutorial here](http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/).  Sorting is actually more of a hassle, since nesting converts your keys to strings (and therefore sort order may be different).  I skipped that and just scanned through the array when assigning the nested networks to the school data objects in this fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/V5DCx/1/  Not super efficient, but you only do it once.

Comment: If you wanted to, you could create two different nested versions of your network array -- one for outgoing networks and one for incoming networks.  All you change is the nesting key function.

Comment: Thanks so much. I see what you are doing in the fiddle and it makes sense, however when I add this to my code, nestedData is returning undefined and thus can't read the values. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...though maybe it has to do with the data loading.  I've put my code in a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/UtHGv/.  I really appreciate the help! I'm slowly getting the hang of d3. :)

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem was with d3.nest.  I had to do a lot of fussing to get the fiddle working, but most of that was because I couldn't access your data files, some was because you had code or variables repeated.  Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UtHGv/2/