# d3 nesting two network csv files (nodes & edges)

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, nested, graph-visualization

what I'm trying to do is d3.nest() one csv into another.

The node list looks like this:

```
id,movie,year,genre
85442,Hamlet,1907,Drama
57421,Don Quijote,1908,Drama
13146,Amleto [I],1908,Drama
85443,Hamlet,1908,Drama
160468,Othello,1909,Drama
160468,Othello,1909,Romance
```

And the edges or links look like this:

```
sourceid,targetid
234,99455
234,125817
234,201681
476,72885
476,188536
476,246634
1028,14948
1028,60050
```

So I would like to nest the edges into the node list by the given IDs.

I'm doing some unclever nesting that doesn't work that looks like this right now:

```
    d3.csv("edges.csv", function(edges){
    d3.csv("nodes.csv", function(nodes){

        var nested_data = d3.nest()
            .key(function(d) { return d.sourceid; })
            .key(function(d) { return d.id; })
            .entries(edges)
            .entries(nodes);     
        console.debug(nested_data);
    });
    });
```

I searched for help and found this: [D3 change elements based on two different datasets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21323220/d3-change-elements-based-on-two-different-datasets)

But I can't get my head around it. Is it really so difficult? Or might there be another way of doing this? I found this visualization (http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/airports.html) which also deals with two csv files and network structures without using nest().

Thanks,

Kim

Comment: It doesn't sound like nesting is the best way to go about this. All you need to do is loop over the list of edges and for each find the source and target in the list of nodes.

Comment: Okay cool thanks! Do you have any examples of the looping. I could write it in plain js but maybe d3 already has some build in methods for this? Once I find a solution I'll post it here.

Comment: There's nothing built in to D3 for this.

Answer (score 0):

Because many people looked at this question, I thought of writing a short follow-up on how this can be solved, to my understanding now.

Lars already gave the right hints. So here just a coded version.

```
d3.csv("edges.csv", function(edges){
d3.csv("nodes.csv", function(nodes){

  var newlist = [];

  var i = edges.length;

  while(i--){

    var edge = edges[i];

      newlist.push(

          nodes[edge.sourceid].x),
          nodes[edge.targetid].y)

      );
  }

  var nested_data = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) { return ... })
      .entries(newlist);  

  });
});
```

It's not fitting the question perfectly because it assumes that the nodes list is ordered by the ids. The two lists above could be itterated over with something like http://underscorejs.org/#find

Hope this helps.